# Python selenium print frame source

Tags: python, selenium, frame

This is my first foray into Selenium. Apologies in advance if this is a stupid/trivial question.

I am trying to scrape information from a webpage. With Python/Selenium I am able to log on to the site and get to the page with the information I need. After the page I need is displayed, I am issuing

```
time.sleep(20)
html_source = driver.page_source
print html_source
```

The "source" that gets printed is different from both the
right click and select view page source and
right click and select This Frame, View Frame source

The required information is in the View Frame source. All of this is in Firefox.

What do I need to do to get to the Frame Source? There is no frame name in the Frame Source.

**Additional information below:**

When I right click and select view page source I get the below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>xxxxxxx Portal</title>
      <base href="https://website.org/page/">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logos/xxxxxxx.ico">
      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://website.org/page/security/csrf.js"> </script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://website.org/page/security/csrf/execute.js"> </script><script>
                    function pushFocus()
                    {
                        frameDetail.focus();
                    }

                    function addInProgressPanel(doc)
                    {
                        var d = doc.createElement('div');
                        d.id="inProgressPane";
                        d.className="freezeOn";

                        var tbl = doc.createElement("table");
                        var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
                        var oi = doc.createElement("img");
                        oi.src= 'https://website.org/page/'+ "images/actions/loading2.gif";
                        var td = doc.createElement("td");
                        td.className="detailFormField";
                        td.bgcolor="red";
                        td.appendChild(oi);
                        row.appendChild(td);

                        td = doc.createElement("td");
                        td.className="inProcessing";
                        td.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Your Request is Being Processed  ..."));
                        row.appendChild(td);

                        d.appendChild(tbl);
                        doc.body.appendChild(d);
                        return d;
                    }

                    function inProgressScreen(type)
                    {
                        var ws = frames["frameDetail"];
                        if(!ws) return true;
                        var ips = ws.document.getElementById("inProgressPane");
                        if(ips)
                        {
                            if(type)  ips.className = 'freezeOn';
                            else      ips.className = 'freezeOff';
                        }else if(type)
                            ips = addInProgressPanel(ws.document);
                    }
                </script></head>
   <frameset id="main" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
      <frame id="frameDetail" name="frameDetail" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="portal/portal.xsl?x=portal.PortalOutline&amp;lang=en&amp;mode=notices">
   </frameset>
</html>
```

When I right click and select This Frame, View Frame source I get

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <base href="https://website.org/xxxxxx/">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
      <title>xxxxxxxx Portal</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/portal/menu.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/portal/header.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/portal/footer.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/portal/jquery-ui-1.8.7.portal.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/portal/fg.menu.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/portal/portal.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/icons.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/portal/notifications.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://website.org/xxxxxxxx/security/csrf.js"> </script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://website.org/xxxxxxxx/security/csrf/execute.js"> </script><script src="scripts/widgets/common.js"></script><script src="scripts/controller.js"></script><script src="scripts/portal.js"></script><script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://website.org/xxxxxxxx/security/csrf/jquery.js"> </script><script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js"></script><script src="scripts/jquery/fg.menu.js"></script><script src="portal/lang/datePickerLanguage.jsp?lang=en"></script><script src="portal/portal.js"></script><script src="portal/portalNoShim.js"></script><script>
```

Lots more code here. Did not paste as it was too long. There is no frame name other than the reference to iSessionFrame below:

```
    </script><script language="javascript" src="portal/grades.js"></script></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="footer">
            <table id="language"><select id="locale" style="width:175px"></select></table>
         </div>
      </div><iframe id="iSessionFrame" name="iSessionFrame" width="0" height="0" src="https://website.org/xxxxxx/white.jsp" style="visibility:hidden;"></iframe></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post URL if you want a more specific answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q:** What do I need to do to get to the Frame Source?

**A:** First you must switch to the wanted frame using the `switch_to` command and then you should use `.page_source` to get the html source.

*Obs.: take a look at Selenium Docs, more specifically at [Moving between windows and frames](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames).*

**Code:**

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("frameDetail"))
driver.page_source
```

Comment: I changed the code as suggested above but get error message

Unable to locate element: frameDetail

The frame does not seem to have a name like others I have seen. 

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this was going to happen, that's why I asked you for the URL... this code is just an idea of how you could access the frame.

Comment: The URL requires a login and password etc. hence I had not provided it. Maybe I am mistaken and it is not a frame?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to switch to the frame using its ID :

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("iSessionFrame"))
driver.page_source
```